# What wrench sizes are needed to maintain a Skyteam ST-50 monkey bike

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, tools

I've made the nutty decision to ride a tiny motorcycle across a foreign country and I'm trying to get a tool kit together.  The bike is a Honda Z-50 mini-trail knock off called a Skyteam ST-50 (aka SkyMini).  What tools will I need to keep the little bike from rattling completely apart and to change a tire if I get a flat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bike in question will certainly rattle apart if you're going on a long adventure, so having tools with you is a good idea.  And if you're in rough terrain, your chance of a flat tire is also pretty high.

The bike has split rims, so changing a tire is a royal pain.  If I were you, I'd bring a "goop" type tire filler canister, and hope that works, as opposed to changing the tire.  But if you do need to change a tire, you'll need a 20mm and a 15mm to remove the shaft, then 12mm and 13mm to get the rim apart.  Also, your replacement tube can't have a very long tire stem or you won't be able to get the air hose on it.

Adjusting the chain tension and changing the oil will require a 10mm and a 17mm, respectively.  The spark plug will require a 16mm (5/8 inch).

I understand that going cross country with all your gear on this bike requires you to pack light, but having the tools will be worth the weight.

[image: bolt sizes for skyteam skymini st-50 monkey bike]